# running npm run build when installing Babel does not add file to output

Tags: javascript, npm, babeljs

after the Babel Setup, I was following a longa a video series in laracasts, I ecountered this problem:

Created a folder, inside the folder did the babel installation via  npm in the command line,

I then created a person.js file for the demo to try it..

After setting up babel, the package.json file was edited and the following has been added:

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0"
  },

  "scripts": {
    "build": "babel src -d output"
  }
}
```

and also added two folders a src folder

inside the person.js i added:

```
class Person {

    constructor(name){
        this.name = name;

    }
}
```

this is the file image

[image: example]

After running this command in the command line i should get :

```
num run build
```

it doesnt add any files to the src folder or the output folder

I tried to look at youtube and answers in here couldn't find a solution

> Solution provided by @loganfsmyth
>
> Thank you very much, it worked I had 3 issues cleared npm cache using
>   'npm cache clean --force' 2. I moved the folder as you said to the src
>   folder, 3. I installed npm again using 'install npm' and it worked
>   perfectly thank you

Comment: If you are on Window make sure your terminal, cmd prompt, bash whatever you are using is being Run as an Administrator. Some files and folders cannot be created without these permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
babel src -d output
```

says

> Compile the `src` folder and put the result in the `output` folder.

Since your `Person.js` file is not in the `src` folder, it has no effect.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked
I had 3 issues cleared npm cache using 'npm cache clean --force' 
2. I moved the folder as you said to the src folder, 
3. I installed npm again using 'install npm' 
and it worked perfectly thank you